# Efficient way to release bitmaps from ArrayList

Tags: android, arrays, bitmap

I store few bitmaps in ArrayList, since Bitmaps are very expensive resource I would like to know if there is an efficient way to release all Bitmaps, when i no longer need the ArrayList or just calling clear on ArrayList is good enough ?

Comment: bitmap.recycle() recycle bitmap when not in use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call `recycle()` on every `Bitmap` your `ArrayList` is holding. Then you can call `clear()`

Comment: just recycle() is sufficient or null assignment to each bitmaps is good to cause aggressive GC ?